# Javascript style display not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On my website people can choose to repair their electronics. When clicked repair my phone, a slider will show up (div id: device_choice). There are 2 options, Phone and Tablet. When they click Tablet, the models of the Phone does also show up. But I don't have that anywhere in my code when Tablet is clicked?!

```
//THESE ARE THE CODE FOR THE PHONE CHOICE:
//This is the first slider where people can choose between device_phone or device_tablet. When clicked slider brand show up! THIS IS THE SLIDER THAT ALSO DOES SHOW UP WHEN .DEVICE_TABLET IS CLICKED!
$(".device_phone").click(function(){
    document.getElementById('device_choice').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('device_phone_brand').style.display='block';
    console.log('Phone chosen');});

//Second slider where apple models shop up for the phone, when device_phone_brand_apple is clicked
$(".device_phone_brand_apple").click(function(){
    document.getElementById('device_phone_brand').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('device_phone_models_apple').style.display='block';
    console.log('Apple models chosen, so show me all Apple phones!');});

//Second slider where samsung models shop up for the phone, when device_phone_brand_samsung is clicked
$(".device_phone_brand_samsung").click(function(){
    document.getElementById('device_phone_brand').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('device_phone_models_samsung').style.display='block';
    console.log('Samsung models chosen, so show me all Samsung phones!');});   


//THESE ARE THE CODE FOR THE TABLET CHOICE:
//This is the first slider where people can choose between device_phone or device_tablet. When clicked slider brand show up!
$(".device_tablet").click(function(){
    document.getElementById('device_choice').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('device_tablet_brand').style.display='block';
    console.log('Tablet chosen');});

//Second slider where apple models shop up for the tablet, when device_tablet_brand_apple is clicked
$(".device_tablet_brand_apple").click(function(){
    document.getElementById('device_tablet_brand').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('device_tablet_models_apple').style.display='block';
    console.log('Apple models chosen, so show me all Apple tablets!');});

//Second slider where samsung models shop up for the tablet, when device_tablet_brand_samsung is clicked
$(".device_tablet_brand_samsung").click(function(){
    document.getElementById('device_tablet_brand').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('device_tablet_models_samsung').style.display='block';
    console.log('Samsung models chosen, so show me all Samsung tablets!');});
```

Here is the CSS where I do hide rows before repair is clicked and also the old code I used before CSS:

```
#device_choice{display:none;}
#device_phone_brand{display:none;}
#device_tablet_brand{display:none;}
#device_phone_models_apple{display:none;}
#device_phone_models_samsung{display:none;}

//THESE ARE THE OLD CODE THAT I USED FOR THE HIDE AND SHOW BUT DOES NOT WORK ANYMORE?!
document.getElementById('device_phone_brand').style.display='none'; // 
document.getElementById('device_tablet_brand').style.display='none'; // 
document.getElementById('device_phone_models_apple').style.display='none'; 
document.getElementById('device_tablet_models_apple').style.display='none'; 
document.getElementById('device_phone_models_samsung').style.display='none'; 
console.log('Hide before click');

$(".device_phone_brand_apple").click(function(){console.log('device_phone_brand_apple klik'); updateProgressBar(33); removeDeviceChoice('phone' ,'apple');});
$(".device_phone_brand_samsung").click(function(){console.log('device_phone_brand_samsung klik'); updateProgressBar(33); removeDeviceChoice('phone' ,'samsung');});
});

function removeDeviceChoice(chosen_device) {
document.getElementById('device_choice').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('device_' + chosen_device+'_brand').style.display='block';
console.log('removeDeviceChoice('+chosen_device+') uitgevoerd');
}
function removeBrandChoice(chosen_device, chosen_brand) {
document.getElementById('device_' + chosen_device + '_brand').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('device_' + chosen_device + '_models_' + chosen_brand).style.display='block';
console.log('removeBrandChoice('+chosen_device+','+chosen_brand+') uitgevoerd');
}
```

Comment: Can we see your HTML and CSS?

Comment: Why don't you use `.hide()` and `.show()`?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] here using [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Jona, CSS is posted. Barmer, I'll try now

Answer (score 1):

Then add your old way of doing it as a function -

```
function hideAll() {
 document.getElementById('device_phone_brand').style.display='none';
 document.getElementById('device_tablet_brand').style.display='none';
 document.getElementById('device_phone_models_apple').style.display='none'; 
 document.getElementById('device_tablet_models_apple').style.display='none'; 
 document.getElementById('device_phone_models_samsung').style.display='none'; 
 document.getElementById('device_tablet_models_samsung').style.display='none'; 
}
```

Then use it as follows

```
$(".device_phone").click(function(){
    document.getElementById('device_choice').style.display='none';
    hideAll(); // hide everything
    document.getElementById('device_phone_brand').style.display='block';
    console.log('Phone chosen');});
```

...

```
$(".device_tablet").click(function(){
    document.getElementById('device_choice').style.display='none';
    hideAll(); // hide everything
    document.getElementById('device_tablet_brand').style.display='block';
    console.log('Tablet chosen');});
```

Comment: No that does not work.

Comment: Also this does not happen with the phone choice. So If i chose Phone, the tablet brands are still hidden

Comment: I have modified my answer, hopefully this works better.

Comment: Nope still not working :(

Comment: I would say double and triple check that all of you `id="..."` parameters match up. It is hard to say what is wrong but I think it is in the HTML.